Configure cert manager in kubernetes without ingress
I have deployed a springboot application with spring cloud gateway in kubernetes.
TLS is enabled on the API gateway, so there is keystore holding the keys and I have configured the credentials and path in application.yml
Im using a self signed certificate and I'm able to access my application.
Now I want to configure cert manager.
In the cert manager documents I see that self signed certificates also can be configured.
Now I'm able store the secret as well.
But this secret must be configured in the ingress service.
In my case I don't have ingress. How should I proceed? Please advise.
